# How to convert a datetime in CurrentCulture format to Gregorian DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I set `Global.asax` as this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PersianCulture fa = new PersianCulture();

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = fa;
    }
```

I want to convert "1392 1 23" to "2013 4 12".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no such thing as "a Persian `DateTime`". A `DateTime` value is *always* a Gregorian calendar value, with no specific formatting. When you format it (usually by calling `ToString`) you can determine how it's formatted - and if you use a culture which uses a non-Gregorian calendar, it will convert the original value into that calendar.

So for example, if you wanted to parse input from a Persian user and then convert that to the equivalent date that an English user would understand, you could use:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(text, persianCulture);
string englishText = date.ToString(englishCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a terms called *Persian Datetime* of *English Datetime*.

From [*MSDN*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx);

> The DateTime value type represents dates and times with values ranging
>   from 00:00:00 (midnight), January 1, 0001 Anno Domini (Common Era)
>   through 11:59:59 P.M., December 31, 9999 A.D. (C.E.) in the **Gregorian
>   calendar.**

When you use `Culture` with your `DateTime`, it will automatically convert to this calender.

> The `CultureInfo` class provides culture-specific information, such as
>   the language, sublanguage, country/region, calendar, and conventions
>   associated with a particular culture. This class also provides access
>   to culture-specific instances of the `DateTimeFormatInfo`,
>   `NumberFormatInfo`, `CompareInfo`, and `TextInfo` objects. These objects
>   contain the information required for culture-specific operations, **such
>   as casing, formatting dates and numbers, and comparing strings.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)

```
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureinfo = 
    new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("11/04/2013", cultureinfo);
```