# How can I get georgian date format in a machine which date format set to another format?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, datetime

I change my machine (win 10) date format to **Persian** and now when I run this code:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(date);
```

I am getting this result: `19/09/1396 10:41:45 ب.ظ`

how can I change this result to `2017/12/10 10:45 pm`?

And is there any config which change whole application date format to georgian?

Comment: do a google search on the `string.Format()` function and how to format different dates.. also look at `CultureInfo or Culture etc..` can you show us what you have tried in regards to converting the `date` to use the `yyyy/dd/mm` format..

Comment: I set my thread CurrentUICulture to System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-IR") or System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US") but there was no result.

Comment: for all we know you set it to German or something.. what my point is , how can anyone help you if you do not post actual code as it pertains to your current issue

Comment: @Navid_pdp11 Looks like you need to set the thread `CurrentCulture` property, rather than the `CurrentUICulture`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally use @Patrick Atrner guide and add this line of code to my Program.CS file and my problem solved...

```
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-IR");
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: This may work, but you are forcing your application to display information in a manner that is potentially different than the culture that the user has set on their machine.  In general, this is a bad idea because the user is expecting to see data in their culture format.  At best, this would be confusing to the end user, and you might as well be using specific formats rather than the culture aware formats.

Answer (score 3):

You need to format the date with the correct culture:

```
static void Main()
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(

        date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us", "en")));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I am providing a USERDEFINED format string as the us format seems to prefere - to /.

Links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

If you always need this kind of format you could cache the CultureInfo for us and wrapp the output into a function for convenience.

Comment: I need get this date in georgian format  and none string datatype...because i am using a datepicker library and i need to set its deault value ... but when i change my machine format it gone to crash mode.. i am using FarsiLibrery which is place in this link : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13664/Farsi-Library-Working-with-Dates-Calendars-and-Dat

Comment: @Navid_pdp11 read up on [how-to-convert-a-datetime-in-currentculture-format-to-gregorian-datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964136/how-to-convert-a-datetime-in-currentculture-format-to-gregorian-datetime) ALl this culture stuff is about Display - the data below is the same - there is no Persion vs Gregorian DateTime object - its just Data that is presented different ways. Kindly do as aksed multiple times already and post the code you use into the question so we can stop guessing what you need and see what you did. :)

Answer (score -2):

If you changed just your machine's date format, then you are specifically telling it to use that format regardless of the culture, so changing the culture of the machine wont work.  If you don't wan't to display dates in that format, then change your machine date format back to what you want.

Comment: is'nt there any way to specify date format in application scope?