# Identify Islamic from Georgian calendar based on datetime string without breaking known standards

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, webapi

I want to find a way to identify the type of calendar, if it is Islamic or Georgia, based on the date time string format.
My idea is to add one character e.g. 'j' at the end of string, hence I could know that the input is an Islamic and vice versa.
The problem that in this way it is breaking the standard, which will cause some side effects e.g. instancing a date object as follows

```
const _ = new Date('1410-04-07T14:58:00.933j')
```

will lead to invalid address

Are there any suggestions?

**Besides these two:**

- safe min date check : e.g. `const calendar = d.year < 1800 ?'Islamic':'georgian'`.
- use explicit identifiers such as adding anther param or header pair value

Comment: You've tagged this with both JavaScript and C#, and the techniques available are incredibly different between the two. Please be explicit about where your code will be running (browser? NodeJS? ASP.NET Web API? .NET Core?)

Comment: No, I have intentionally done that as I am talking about standards which are popular in most programming languages e.g. ISO 8601

Comment: for your question, I have a RESTful .net WebApi that provides a UTC DateTime (specifically: date) and should consume both georgian and Islamic calendars and must identify them so if it is an Islamic it will be converted into georgian calendar during data binding phenomenon and based only on the DateTime received

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47742696/how-can-i-get-georgian-date-format-in-a-machine-which-date-format-set-to-another can help,